# Have enough room but still needs more for high density?

Tags: simcity-2013

So I was zoning my city, doing some experiences and then after I planned the layout of the roads to get the maximum number of High Density buildings back-to-back, I was very happy with the result and started buying the roads and zoning all over the place.

But then, after a while, buildings wanted to upgrade their density so they did it, but noticed that a row of houses didn't increase. Moused over the houses and they said:
 "Not enough room to increase density"

I checked the size that the houses needed and the little rectangule is green,
 and green = good to go? (See picture below)
[image]

The road of the houses is the best quality, and I dezoned that area just for demonstration. And I don't want houses or anything else in the main avenue.

So.. how is the game not upgrading the houses? Seems like everything (or not, for some reason) is perfect for the grow...

Comment: We don't put solved in the title here at Arqade.  If you've fixed your problem, accept the answer that did so, or write your own (which you've done), and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

The little rectangle will be green because you are zoning residential.  The color of the rectangle indicates the space available:

- bright green : all densities may fit.
- darkened green: only room for low density. (as seen in picture)
- red: no density will fit.

Answer (score 0):

One picky thing I've seen with density upgrades at times is that, if a building attempts to upgrade density, it can't do so if the building it tries to turn into would run over a neighbour that's not yet ready to upgrade. Look at the happiness map and see if the neighbours are also ready for an upgrade - if not, you have to wait for them.

Comment: Those houses were all happy and ready to upgrade but they couldn't because actually there was not enough space... I figured it out: There are two different rectangules that can appear to mark the space a building will ocuppy, according with the road capacity - a light green one and a dark green one (this one is shown at the picture). I don't know if this color difference is on purpose or some kind of bug... The light green color tells us that, (and always according with road capacity), a build can upgrade to higher density and that space is the space needed. The dark green color tells